# Regular Expression to exclude a String around the required String

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, rainmeter, regex-look-ahead

In between a **HTML code**:

`...<div class="..."><a class="..." href="...">I need this String only</a></div>...`

How do I write Regular Expression (for Rainmeter which uses Perl RegEx) such that:

-required string `"I need this String only"` is grouped to be extracted,

-the HTML link tag `<a>...</a>` might be
***absent or present*** & can be present in between the required string and multiple times as well.

**My attempt:**

(?siU) `<div class="...">.*[>]{0,1}(.*)[</a>]{0,1}</div>`
where:

```
.*= captures every characters except newline{<a class ... "}
[>]{0,1}= accepts 0 or 1 times presence of > {upto >}
(.*)= captures my String
[</a>]{0,1}= accepts 0 or 1 times presence of </a>
```

this, of course, doesn't work as I want,
*This gives output with HTML linking preceding my string*
so my question is

***How to write a better(and working) RegEx?***

Comment: You should use `XPath` or a XML parser instead. Regex isn't a recommanded approach for this kind of content.

Comment: `[</a>]` is a character class that matches any of the characters, not the string `</a>`.

Comment: `[</a>]` means that character set, `<` or `/` or `a` or `>`. Maybe you meant `(</a>){0,1}`? Also, `.*` will try to match as much as it can. `.*?` might work because it would say match as little as possible.

Comment: [Why a regex *really* isn't good enough for HTML and XML, even for "simple" tasks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11116478)

Comment: Actually, because everything after the `.*` in `<div class="...">.*` is optional, that first `.*` will match all the way to `</div>` and everything else in between will match to empty strings. I agree with Amessihel and choroba, you really want a proper XML or HTML parser for this, not a regular expression.

Comment: That being said, maybe this would help you: `<a[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>`. Here I'm relaxing your requirements to just matching something within the `<a>` tag, and assuming that `<` and `>` will not occur elsewhere, since they should be escaped as `&lt;` if they did. The key is using `[^>]*` and `[^<]*` to say match anything but the angle brace I'm next expecting as a delimiter.

Answer (score -1):

Even though I agree with the advice to use a real parser for this problem, this regular expression should solve your problem:

```
<div [^.<>]|*>(?:[^<>]*<a [^<>]*>)*([^<>]*)(?:</a>)*</div>
```

Logic:

- require `<div ...>` at the beginning and `</div>` at the end.
- allow and ignore `<a ...>` before the matched text arbitrarily many times
- allow and ignore `</a>` after the matched text arbitrarily many times
- ignore any text before any `<a ...>` with `[^<>]*` in front of it. Using `.*` would also work, but then it would skip all text arbitrarily up to the **last** instance of `<a ...>` in your string.
- I use `[^<>]*` instead of `.*` to match non-tag text in a protected way, since literal `<` and `>` are not allowed.
- I use `(?:...)` to group without capturing. If that is not supported in your programming language, just use `(...)` instead, and adjust which match you use.

Caveat: this won't be fully general but should work for your problem as described.